# Making a generic method to update entity framework many-to-many navigation property

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

This is a method i have to update a single navigation property in a many-to-many relationship, but its too specific for the DAL. I was wondering if anyone could help make this method more generic so it can handle any entity being passed in.

I would pass in two parameters: the entity to be updated, and the navigation property to be modified.

The below method works with an item table and a property table that are involved in a many-to-many relationship. An item can be assigned to many properties and a property can have many items.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

```
public void UpdateItems(Property property)
        {
            using (var context = new PropertyManagementDBEntities())
            {
                var customerInDb = context.Properties.Include("Items")
                    .Single(c => c.propertyId == property.propertyId);



                // Remove types
                foreach (var itemInDb in customerInDb.Items.ToList())
                    if (!property.Items.Any(t => t.itemId == itemInDb.itemId))
                        customerInDb.Items.Remove(itemInDb);

                // Add new types
                foreach (var item in property.Items)
                    if (!customerInDb.Items.Any(t => t.itemId == item.itemId))
                    {
                        context.Items.Attach(item);
                        customerInDb.Items.Add(item);
                    }

                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Might be a better question for http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this.

```
public void UpdateItems<TEntity,TRelated>(
    // Entity with new list of related items
    TEntity entity, 
    // Selector for the key of the entity element
    Func<TEntity,object[]> entityKeySelector,
    // Selector for the related items of the Property
    Expression<Func<TEntity,ICollection<TRelated>>> relatedItemsSelector,
    // Comparer of related items
    Func<TRelated, TRelated, bool> relatedItemsComparer)
    where TEntity : class
    where TRelated : class
{
    using (var context = new TCtx())
    {
        // get the Keys for the entity
        object[] entityKeyValues = entityKeySelector.Invoke(entity);
        // gets the entity entity from the DB
        var entityInDb = context.Set<TEntity>().Find(entityKeyValues);
        // loads the related entities from the DB
        context.Entry(entityInDb).Collection(relatedItemsSelector).Load();

        // gets the list of properties in the passed entity
        var newRelatedItems 
            = relatedItemsSelector.Compile().Invoke(entity);

        // Gets the list of properties loaded from the DB
        var relatedItemsInDb 
            = relatedItemsSelector.Compile().Invoke(entityInDb);

        // Remove related elements
        foreach (var relatedInDb in relatedItemsInDb)
            if (!newRelatedItems.Any(item => relatedItemsComparer
                 .Invoke(relatedInDb, item)))
            {
                // If the related intem in DB is not in the entity, remove it
                relatedItemsInDb.Remove(relatedInDb);
            }

        // Add new types
        foreach (var item in newRelatedItems)
            if (!relatedItemsInDb.Any(itemInDb => relatedItemsComparer
                .Invoke(itemInDb, item)))
            {
                // Attach the item to the Set
                context.Set<TRelated>().Attach(item);
                // If the related item is not in the DB add it
                relatedItemsInDb.Add(item);
            }

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

If your entities have only one key field, you can change the entity key selector to this one: `Func<TEntity,object> entityKeySelector` which makes it easier to use (or implement both signatures).

For example if you have items which can have different colors, you can invoke it like this

```
ManyToManyHandler<MyDbContext>.UpdateItems(
    item,
    i => new object[] {i.ItemId},
    i => i.Colors,
    (c1, c2) => c1.ColorId == c2.ColorId
    );
```

with the second overload:

```
ManyToManyHandler<MyDbContext>.UpdateItems(
    item,
    i => i.ItemId,
    i => i.Colors,
    (c1, c2) => c1.ColorId == c2.ColorId
    );
```

*NOTE: I'm using the class ManyToManyHandler which is a generic static class with TCtx as a generic parameter, and UpdateItems as an static method*